# Can I provide low-voltage power for an HVAC humidifier from a standard outlet?

Tags: wiring, furnace, humidifier

I recently bought an Aprilaire humidifier to replace an old one that came with the house, which I thought was broken.

After connecting the water (which does work and isn't clogged) and the wiring to the existing wiring that goes into the furnace control board it still doesn't work.

I believe that the old wiring that connected the humidifier to the furnace is probably faulty or possibly even that the humidifier part of the furnace control board is faulty.

Is there anyway that I can just rewire the red and white wires from the humidifier and humidifier thermostat through some kind of transformer and then have the whole thing just plug into a wall outlet?

If so what kind of transformer/wiring do I need to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Before you go to the trouble, why not do a little investigating? A basic multimeter is an inexpensive and valuable tool to have around. Find out if you're getting 24v at the humidifier.